# Why Table to Excel tool does not work properly in ArcGIS Pro?

Tags: arcgis-pro, excel, table-to-excel

I have been using a Python/ArcPy code use to generate many Excel files (.xlsx) from shapefiles. After the last Pro update end users start complaining that they get message when they try to open those Excel files.

First, I thought it was something wrong from my end, code, server etc. but when I do the process manually. I got the same error.

When I  try to open ESRI generated Excel file I get the message below

[image]

Then I click Yes and get this message

[image]

It seems nothing get lost but it is frustrating popping multiple windows and make users think they did something wrong or something wrong with the file itself.

I found this
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18539267/xlsx-error-removed-records-named-range-from-xl-workbook-xml-part-when-tried/44416204#44416204

but I don't have any control of the template or problem mentioned here.

Is there way to fix our own or we need ESRI to fix that?

Comment: Have you actually fired this off to ESRI support? If you don't nothing will get done.

Comment: @Hornbydd I shared it at GeoNet. Hopefully, they will address the issue soon.

Comment: Even GeoNet isn't the right place for bug reports. An actual bug report will tag a defect to your customer ID, allowing you get status reports as the defect is resolved.

Comment: It's an issue with `openpyxl` which is a non-Esri python library that is included ArcGIS Pro's python environment. Can you edit your question and include the openpyxl version (the simplest way to find this is open the ArcGIS Pro python window and type `import openpyxl;print(openpyxl.__version__)` and your ArcGIS Pro version.

Comment: @Vince Unfortunately, I can not report bugs ESRI directly but I requested permission for the future problems. Thank you!

Comment: @user2856 Are you sure it is openpyxl issue? I am using 3.0.3 along with Pro 2.6. I tried both upgraded 3.0.5 and and downgraded 3.0.0 version but I still had the same error.

Comment: Am I supposed to delete a closed question?

Comment: it's fixed in Pro 2.6.1. See BUG-000132901 on https://pro.arcgis.com/en/pro-app/get-started/release-notes.htm